# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded on Scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I'M Scala developer,I am getting this error in a **Routes** file it contains **1008 lines** if I add another Line that's throw given below error..

```
Uncaught error from thread [sbt-web-scheduler-1] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[sbt-web]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] [04/12/2016 15:17:32.883] [sbt-web-scheduler-1] [ActorSystem(sbt-web)] exception on LARSÆ timer thread
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:375)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

        at akka.event.Logging$Info$.apply(Logging.scala:665)
        at akka.event.BusLogging.notifyInfo(Logging.scala:1140)
        at akka.event.LoggingAdapter$class.info(Logging.scala:950)
        at akka.event.BusLogging.info(Logging.scala:1128)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:382)
[ERROR] [04/12/2016 15:18:33.808] [sbt-web-scheduler-1] [ActorSystem(sbt-web)] Uncaught error from thread [sbt-web-scheduler-1]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

How Many lines accepted in Routes? How can I solve this?

Editor: Eclipse

Thanks By,
B.UdayaKumar

Comment: Basically, you are running out of the memory. What is the memory size that are you using? Try increasing the memory size by using -Xmx option to the JVM. May be try increasing to 1GB

Comment: Thanks mohit.. I will try it..

Comment: @Udayakumar Allocating memory is always more expensive than not allocating memory. Read this for the future! https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this error is thrown when there is insufficient space to allocate an object in the Java heap. In this case, The garbage collector cannot make space available to accommodate a new object, and the heap cannot be expanded further. Also, this error may be thrown when there is insufficient native memory to support the loading of a Java class. In a rare instance, a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` may be thrown when an excessive amount of time is being spent doing garbage collection and little memory is being freed.

You're essentially running out of memory to run the process smoothly. Options that come to mind are:

- Specify more memory using the `JAVA_OPTS` enviroment variable, try something in between like -`Xmx1G`.
- You can also tune your GC manually by enabling `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

For more options on GC tuning refer [Concurrent Mark Sweep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html)

Increasing the HEAP size should fix your routes limit problem.

Comment: @udayakumarb If the answer has solved your problem you can mark it as Accepted answer

Comment: I do not share your opinion about 'just increasing the HEAP size', what if the user is running multiple apps in the background? I personally think that that is just a dirty fix

Comment: @S.R Lobato I agree just increasing the heap size is a dirty fix. But if an application requires x mb of heap just to start you should allocate more than that in this case the apps that he is running. I would also suggest to run a profiler and see where is all the memory getting allocated or if there is a memory leak. If the memory allocation are genuine and required the right thing to do would still be increasing the heap size.

Comment: @Vishnu667 I do think it is a quick fix to just start, but overall I think that following these tips: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic are the best to begin with. "Choosing the right algorithms and data structures should always be your priority", preventing is better than solving on the long run.

Comment: @Rafael that is a good academic answer ("use more efficient algorithms") but the reality is that we can't tune every library we use, or even every module in our own code when the app is complex with many developers. Some programs need more memory.